# Exim: Accept suffix aliases as FROM address in ACL

Tags: exim, access-control-list

I am using exim for outgoing mails. For SMTP authenticated users, I have already added several ACLs and want to add another one allowing suffix aliases. Suffix aliases are email addresses such as "user+alias@example.com".

The environment looks as follows:

- The username (full email address) is stored in `$authenticated_id`
- The set FROM address is stored in `$sender_address`
- The "user" in "user@example.com" can be found in `${local_part:$authenticated_id}`
- The domain name of the authenticated user is in `${domain:$authenticated_id}`

Now I want to achieve an ACL rule that looks as follows:

```
# accept if FROM address is a suffix alias of authenticated address
accept
  condition = ${if match {$sender_address} {${local_part:$authenticated_id}+{*}@${domain:$authenticated_id}} }
  logwrite = AUTH OK - FROM address $sender_address is a suffix alias of authenticated user
```

Unfortunately, the ACL rule seems to not be correct. I am receiving the following error message:

```
failed to expand ACL string "${if match {$sender_address} {${local_part:$authenticated_id}+{*}@${domain:$authenticated_id}} }": curly-bracket problem in conditional yes/no parsing: 'yes' part did not start with '{'
```

**Q: What's the problem with the above condition, and what would a correct condition to achieve this look like?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several times, I just got it working. This is how the rule is supposed to look like:

```
# accept if FROM address is a suffix alias of authenticated address
accept
  condition = ${if match {$sender_address} {(${local_part:$authenticated_id}\+.*@${domain:$authenticated_id})}}
  logwrite = AUTH OK - FROM address $sender_address is a suffix alias of authenticated user
```